# MySQL how to select and left join two tables by condition on first one depends on itself

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables answers and answerSets, its need to select all answers if another Answer is equals filtered option

table answerSet

```
id       user       otherData
-------------------------- 
1         Ali       10:20
2         Mohammad  11:40
3         Bob       09:00  
4         Reza      00:20
```

and answers are :

```
id       answerSetId  questionid  answer 
----------------------------------------- 
10         1            300        false (NOk)
11         1            301          a ( don't need this)
12         1            302          ---  
13         1            303          ---
14         2            300        true (OK)
15         2            301          b (<=need this)
16         2            302          ---  
17         2            303          ---
18         3            300        true (OK)
19         3            301          xz (<=need this)
20         3            302          ---  
21         4            303          ---
22         5            300        true (OK)
23         6            301          yyy (<=need this)
24         7            302          ---  
25         8            303          ---
```

I think its need to use inner join and left join but I don't know how

so I need something like below

```
id       user           questionid      answer 
------------------------------------------------------ 
15     Mohammad            301          b (<=need this)
19         Bob             301          xz (<=need this)
23       Reza              301          yyy (<=need this)
```

I try to do something but I don't know exactly

```
SELECT * FROM answers left Join answerSets on answerSet_id=answersets.id WHERE questionid=300 and answer=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `JOIN` with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.*, ans.answer
FROM answers a JOIN
     answerSets ans
     ON a.answerSet_id = ans.id
WHERE a.questionid = 301 AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM answersets a2
              WHERE a2.answerSet_id = a.answerSet_id AND
                    a2.questionid = 300
                    a2.answer = 'true'
             );
```

Comment: please edit your answer, ans2 is not defined and ans.answerSet_id is not avalable, Do you mean ans.id ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to `JOIN`. Since you need only `user` column from `answerSet`, try this.

```
SELECT answers.id,
    (SELECT user FROM answerSet where id=answers.answerSetId) AS user,
    answers.questionid,
    answers.answer 
FROM answers 
WHERE questionid=301 AND 
    answerSetId IN (SELECT answerSetId 
                    FROM answers 
                    WHERE questionid=300 AND 
                          answer='true'
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tow SELECT-LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT answerSet_id as id FROM answers LEFT JOIN answerSet on answerSet_id=answerset.id 
WHERE answer=true) ast
LEFT JOIN
answers a
on ast.id=a.answerSet_id
where formanswers_questionId=301
```